# Is it possible to have Vim automatically treat regular expressions as if \v was given in the pattern?

Tags: regex, vim

The title question is straightforward; I'm looking for an option similar to `magic` so that the Vim regexes are sufficiently Perly.  I'm tired of having to type `\v` any time I need to do some capturing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, and enabling such option, if it will be added, will cause almost all plugins to break. Of course, you could use mappings and commands, for example here is my `:S` command:

```
command -nargs=1 -range   S execute "<line1>,<line2>s".<q-args>[0].'\v'.
                                                      \<q-args>[1:]
```

. Usage is similar to `:s`, but it enables `\v`. You could also add a mapping

```
noremap / /\v
```

and define a set of custom functions, like the following:

```
function Substitute(expr, pat, sub, flags)
    return substitute(a:expr, '\v'.a:pat, a:sub, a:flags)
endfunction
```